# Mips .space directive Memory address out of bounds

Tags: assembly, mips

My code looks like this:

```
.data
.space 40
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a number:"
.text

main:
lui $a0, 0x1029 # accessing address(prompt) after 40 bytes (41th byte)
addi $v0, $0, 4
syscall
```

By running the above code, I'm having a memory address out of bounds error and "null" is printed to the console. I'm confused as to why is this error occurring?

On the other hand if I replace the first line in main label with the following two lines:

```
lui $a0, 0x1000
addi $a0, $a0, 40
```

Then it works fine.

Comment: Doing `lui $a0, 0x1029` will produce address `0x10290000` not `0x10000029` as it sets the upper 16 bits. Hence the name: load upper immediate. Consult an instruction set reference. PS: you should be using `la` unless you are really sure about your addresses.

Comment: Well, I'm working on an assignment and I'm only allowed to run this on bare mode. So can't use la.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lui $a0, 0x1029` sets `$a0` to `0x10290000`, the immediate left-shifted by 16.  That's the whole point of `lui`, load *upper* immediate.

`lui $a0, 0x1000` / `addi $a0, $a0, 40` sets `$a0` to `0x10000028`, which is the address of `prompt`.

It's what `la $a0, prompt` would assemble to.

---

Besides putting the 0x29 in the wrong place, it's 0x28.  Remember that the starting address is 0, so the 41st byte of the .data section has offset 40.

The first byte of the data section has offset 0.

Comment: This make so much sense now. Thanks!